# Prevent zooming out in leaflet R-Map?

Tags: r, zooming, leaflet

I made a leaflet map with the leaflet R-package.

This is what the result looks like:
[image]

I am very happy with it, but when I embed it into a website and scroll down the article with my laptop I often accidentally zoom out of the map which then looks like this:

[image]

The user have to zoom back in too have a look at the intersteing part of the map which really annoys me.

Is there a way to freeze the part of the map like you can zoom in as usual but can't zoom out more than like on the image? I tried setting the View in my code but you still can zoom out so I deleted that part.

```
    mymap <- leaflet() %>% 

addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas") %>%
addPolygons(data = dortmund, 
            fillColor = ~palette(student1$Anteil),  ## we want the polygon filled with 
            ## one of the palette-colors
            ## according to the value in student1$Anteil
            fillOpacity = 0.6,         ## how transparent do you want the polygon to be?
            color = "darkgrey",       ## color of borders between districts
            weight = 1.5,            ## width of borders
            popup = popup1,         ## which popup?
            group="<span style='color: #7f0000; font-size: 11pt'><strong>2000</strong></span>")%>%  
            ## which group?
            ## the group's name has to be the same as later in "baseGroups", where we define 
            ## the groups for the Layerscontrol. Because for this layer I wanted a specific 
            ## color and size, the group name includes some font arguments.  

## for the second layer we mix things up a little bit, so you'll see the difference in the map!
addPolygons(data = dortmund, 
            fillColor = ~palette(student2$Anteil), 
            fillOpacity = 0.2, 
            color = "white", 
            weight = 2.0, 
            popup = popup2, 
            group="2014")%>%
addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("<span style='color: #7f0000; font-size: 11pt'><strong>2000</strong></span>", ## group 1
                   "2014" ## group 2
    ),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))%>% ## we want our control to be seen right away
addLegend(position = 'topleft', ## choose bottomleft, bottomright, topleft or topright
           colors = c('#fee0d2',
                      '#fcbba1',
                      '#fc9272',
                      '#fb6a4a',
                      '#ef3b2c',
                      '#cb181d',
                      '#a50f15',
                      '#67000d'), 
           labels = c('0%',"","","","","","",'26%'),  ## legend labels (only min and max)
           opacity = 0.6,      ##transparency 
           title = "relative<br>amount")   ## title of the legend
```

Forgive my bad english skills. If it's important to answer my question, full code's here: http://journocode.com/2016/01/28/your-first-choropleth-map/.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace your addProviderTiles with the following (set whatever zoom levels you want for max and min:

```
addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas",
        options = providerTileOptions(minZoom=10, maxZoom=18))
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! For me it worked with `addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldGrayCanvas",
                   options = tileOptions(minZoom=10, maxZoom=16))}`

Answer (score 0):

What I, [additionally to set minimal and maximal zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35564013/4112892), find very helpful is a "home" button that flies you back to the initial map boundings and zoom.

```
leaflet() |>
  addTiles() |> 
    addEasyButton(easyButton(icon = "fas fa-home",
                             title = "Fly back home",
                             position = "topleft",
                             onClick = JS(paste0(
                               "function(btn, map) {
                                      map.fitBounds([
                                        [", -11.25, ",", 40, "], ",
                                        "[", 47.9, ",", -15.37, "]
                                        ])
                                      }"
                             )
                             ))) |>
    fitBounds(lng1 = 40, lat1 = -11.25,
              lng2 = -15.37, lat2 = 47.9)
```

The bounding box of the geo object can be calculated with `sf::st_bbox()`.