# R Leaflet: Zoom Control Level

Tags: r, leaflet, zooming

I am trying to set zoom out maximum in my R Leaflet map. I follow an example of a previous question/answer in [Prevent zooming out in leaflet R-Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556197/prevent-zooming-out-in-leaflet-r-map)  , but it doesn't work. The line that should be able to do this is:

```
options = providerTileOptions(minzoom = 1, maxzoom = 10))
```

Can you guys can help me to figure out why?

Here is code:

```
 deck_lf_par_map <- leaflet(lpoints) %>%
               addPolygons(data = dio, noClip=T,
                           weight = 4,
                           dashArray="5, 1",
                           color = "black",
                           fillOpacity = .01,
                           smoothFactor = 0) %>%
               setView(lng = mean(lpoints$long), lat = mean(lpoints$lat), zoom = 09) %>%
               addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                                group = "Toner", 
                                options = providerTileOptions(minzoom = 1, maxzoom = 10)) %>%
               addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
               addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap",    
                                group = "Topo") %>%
               addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik", group = "Mapnik") %>%
               addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",     group = "CartoDB") %>%
              setMaxBounds((dioc@bbox[1,1] - .3), 
                           (dioc@bbox[2,1] - .3), 
                           (dioc@bbox[1,2] + .3), 
                           (dioc@bbox[2,2] + .3)) %>%
              addMarkers(lpoints$long, 
                         lpoints$lat, 
                         popup=ppopup, 
                         icon = tec_icon, 
                         group="Parishes", 
                         clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
             addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Toner", "OSM", "Topo", "Mapnik", "CartoDB"),
                       options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. It's `minZoom` and `maxZoom` (notice the capital **Z**)
2. You need the options in each `Tile` function that you want to set
   the zoom levels for.

---

```
library(leaflet)

## the first two tiles have a zoom level control - the others don't
leaflet() %>%
    setView(lng = 144, lat = -37, zoom = 09) %>%
    addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite",
                     group = "Toner", 
                     options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 8, maxZoom = 10)) %>%
    addTiles(group = "OSM",
             options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 8, maxZoom = 10)) %>%
    addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap",    
                     group = "Topo") %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik", group = "Mapnik") %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",     group = "CartoDB") %>%
    addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Toner", "OSM", "Topo", "Mapnik", "CartoDB"),
                     options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
```